# Issue with Firebase Android Button Size

Tags: java, android, android-layout

[image]

It's working good and everything else is good but the size of Facebook button is not good.
I tried to edit it from xml in several ways but button size remains the same
Can anyone please Help?

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/forgot_password"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:typeface="normal"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:background="@drawable/tw__transparent"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_width="130dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/facebook_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: you want to increase height or decrease width ?

Comment: can you post the full xml

Comment: increase height

Comment: Ive posted full xml

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if You can Use Padding Like this so increase size but this in use worst case

        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <!--  in reguler case customise button with xml
    in Drawable  ic_facebook_button-->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="32dp" />
        <solid android:color="#5476b8" />
        <padding
            android:bottom="5dp"
            android:left="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:top="5dp" />
    </shape>

//Use in Layout xml
              <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonFacebook"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/facebookbutton"
                    android:text="@string/facebook_connect"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_facebook"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Comment: Thanks Vasupujy, it helped

Comment: if it would help you then  please accept and up vote

Comment: he cant up vote with out 10 rep , i will do it for him :)

Answer (score 0):

you can specify height

```
 <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

increase height as per requirement

Comment: see if button has scaletype property if yes write this line

   android:ScaleType="fitxy"